# What does T indicate in this function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What does T stand for in $w^T$? And why does the differentiation of $w^T*x$ in the innermost function yield w?

$( 1 , . . . , _ ) = (1 + (^ *  + )),  ∈ ℝ^ ,  ∈ ℝ^ ,  ∈ ℝ$
(w, b constants).

Solution:
$$∇() =\frac{(^ *  + )*w}{1 + (^ *  + )} = (^ *  + ) $$

where  is the sigmoid function

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Comment: Why do we need to transpose in this context? And why is the T lost when differentiating?

Comment: That is wrong. The gradient of $x \mapsto w^T x$ is $w^T$.